# The significance of the word "For"

Tags: sentence-construction

How significant is the word "For" in constructions like, **"I was hoping we could talk (for) a while."**

If we left out the "For" in constructing similar sentences, would that grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, both options are correct. However, "talk for a while" seems to be about 5 times more common than "talk a while", see this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talk+a+while%2C+talk+for+a+while&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctalk%20a%20while%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctalk%20for%20a%20while%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: "For" when used to indicate time length can be dropped, especially in frequently used expressions as :  We had to wait an hour.  But there are cases where the drop of for can lead to ambiguity.

Comment: "Talk a while" strikes me (British) as American. I would say "stay a while", and "wait a while", but I can't think of any other verbs where I would omit the "for".